# Moving to a new domain - what to do to minimize visitor loss

Tags: domains, search-engines, 301-redirect, visitors

I want to move my website to a new domain. Would be nice if you can share some experience or suggestion to minimize loss of visitors.

In google webmaster tools there is an option which allows to move search result to a new domain. It should be done through a 301 permamently redirected page? Can you tell me what I have to do for this? do I need to put this 301 page in every page I had in old domain?

More ideas are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you keeping all the pages the same or are you restructuring/renaming as well?

Comment: @paulmorriss I will keep the pages as before. Nothing is going to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case [the answer I gave to this question yesterday](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16670/site-wide-redirect-with-tomcat4/16672#16672) will redirect all the pages in one go (even though you're not using Tomcat). Search engines will notice the 301 and start indexing you at the new domain. Google will know you've moved too.

Comment: Thanks. So this will be the only required action?

Comment: Yes, that should be it.

Comment: Here are some additional tips we have in our Help Center in case you want to read more: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=83105